# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null

Tags: java, apache, web-services, httprequest, httpresponse

I have googled but many concerns was "**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null**", but in my case error was "**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null**"

I am trying to post a request using following code

```
StringEntity reqContent = new StringEntity(xmlData);
reqContent.setContentType("text/xml");

HttpPost req = new HttpPost(serverURL);
req.setEntity(reqContent);

httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connMgr, params);

httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(req);
```

After executing the request I am getting "Target host is null".
I am giving a valid host. Does this error comes when Target host which I am trying to access is not available?

Comment: Are you giving a valid domain or a valid url. This error actually states out that you probabely missing the protocol in the url. This happens if you just send the domain (without the protocolk http:// or https://)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending a request , somehow my URL which I want to send the request to is getting null which caused this issue when I am trying to execute a request.

Answer (score 3):

In my case also "http://" was missing